Firmware upgrade of an old Ender 3
I've inherited a Creality Ender 3. I suspect one of the early ones, as it's firmware is Marlin 0.0.5, dated May 2020.
I'd like to upgrade the firmware, but can't work out which version to use. The main reason for the upgrade is to support the change filament option.


Start by working out which version of the mainboard is inside

Thank you for that, I should have mentioned it has a micro USB connector at the front. Not USB-C.

Marlin 0.0.5 does not exist, I suspect you are referring to the 2.0 branch. M600  is the filament change command and M603 to configure the filament change setup. Looking  at the implementation version, it should be present in Marlin 1.1.0. Open the printer and look at the main controller board, there should be a version number of the board written by the silk screen.

Thanks, here's a photo of the Printer Information. Could you interpret it for me?  https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/vbq123j2fsdxo1oh1i4qz/ender3.jpg?rlkey=r3ziy7x5fbxjpwpfx6wpj5gp6&dl=0

That photo only gives us information that you have already provided. To help you further, you will need to physically open the bottom of the printer and get the version of the board as previously instructed.

The board has a numer, e.g. this board has version 4.2.2, add a photo of your board to the question by [edit].

I really didn't want to take the printer apart, but after a google, it's so simple. The board is version V4.2.2, here's a picture  https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/dl44gfc2uq2ord8qbven2/Motherboard.jpg?rlkey=49w7su8cikyahbkg9n9qiz3eb&dl=0

I think this is the right firmware, is that correct?  https://marlin.crc.id.au/firmware/Ender%203%20Max%20-%20v4.2.2%20Board/

Actually that's not official, which firmware would be the official route, This one ? Ender-3 4.2.2 mainboard (32bit) 28 Jan. 2021
